# Is the dual of a flat module flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, flatness

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $T$ be a integral, regular, projective $k$-scheme and $X$ another projective, integral $k$-scheme. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent (pure) sheaf on $X \times_k T$, which is flat over $T$. Is the dual sheaf $\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{X \times_k T}}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{O}_{X \times_k T})$ going to be flat over $T$?

Comment: What are your thoughts about?

Comment: @Crostul I know that it is true over a non-empty open subset of $T$ but skeptical over the whole of $T$.

Comment: in the noetherian case, coherent + flat = locally free of finite rank, right? but I am not sure if we may apply this here due to the relative flatness condition. it only settles the case $X=k$.

Comment: If the base $T$ is one dimensional then being flat is equivalent to being torsion-free. But this doesn't help in the higher dimensional cases.